# Posts don't appear on the Blog page

Tags: posts, blog

I am in the process of building a book review site for my daughter using the twentyten theme. 
For some reason the "Blog" page does not display any of the posts that I have written. I have searched the entire forum and have tried various things such as de-activating all plugins and reactivating them, but that has not helped.
Can anyone help?
The URL is http://teenbooktalk.co.uk

Comment: TwentyTen should be using `body_class` but on your blog page the output is not what I expected. It should be `echo`ing more than one class, so I suspect you've made significant changes to the theme. I can't tell what template file that is. Please post the relevant code.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need to set the `Settings -> Reading` option for the posts page.

Answer (score -1):

@Marc, assuming you have tried adding the page to the main menu. You can try doing the following:
 1. Create a category called "Blog" 
 2. Assign all posts to "Blog"
 3. Add this category to main menu (you can expand the screen options by clicking the up side down triangle button on the top right of your screen and select category)
 4. Refresh

After the above steps you should be able to see your posts.

Comment: Hello Natalie, that's perfect - it worked! Do you know why this happened? I have another site where I never had this problem at all and I did not use categories either.

Comment: This is not the correct fix, you are now showing an archive page. What are your reading settings like? You need to set a page as the 'Posts page' for the correct templates to be used.